# Need to post Live Stream data from Social Plugin ONLY to a secret group

Tags: streaming, facebook-social-plugins

I am creating a site for a secret group on Facebook.

This group would interact on the site and would post and repost/reply on the site - I want all these posts to be posted only to the Secret Group.

Can I get some ideas or directions please?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the group is secret should not change the way you interact with it, at least as I see it, maybe I'm wrong.

The Group object ([http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#feed)) has the "feed" connection which is:

> This connection corresponds to the Group's wall. You can create a
>   link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the
>   GROUP_ID/feed connection

Each posting is done by issuing a POST request to a specific url along side the required parameters, all of these different requests are described in the linked page.